# Help with time travel story

Tags: alternate-reality

A time traveller intends to change the past, specifically the medieval age, with modern weaponry. The problem? How would he bring along with him all the arsenal he requires in order to take down an entire army? So far my solution is he hijacks a ship full of military equipment complete with tanks and jets and travels to the past along with the ship. Supplies won't be an issue since he's only going to be there for awhile.

Comment: You should keep your story the way it is: the time traveler is a total lackwit dufus but he pulls it off, hijacks the ship and jumps it thru time.  Then in the medieval age he shows up with this ship, its scared crew and all of these amazing weapons none of them know how to use and none of which are fueled up.  I really want to know what happens next!

Comment: We already know the best way to wipe out a massive amounts of people who are approximately of medieval levels of knowledge, because it nearly completely happened in europe once or twice, and then actually did happen in south america once: Disease warfare.

Your protagonist takes a load of diseased blankets and a full course of antibiotics with him.

Answer (score 6):

> he hijacks a ship full of military equipment complete with tanks and jets and travels to the past along with the ship

then as soon as he lands in the past he realizes how naive he was. Tanks and jets don't pilot themselves alone, and need crew to be operated, fuel to be propelled and regular maintenance to stay operative.

All of those things are missing in the middle age, so he just carried in the past a lot of scrap metal.

Much better if he had taken with him a lot of AK-47 and related ammunition

- AK-47 is notoriously easy to operate and maintain, thus he can easily train some locals in using it. Making spare parts will likely be impossible, though
- considering the middle age tactics, holding an army at bay with a few well placed soldiers firing their AK-47 will be a piece of cake

Comment: Also, medieval armies are prone to losing morale and running away. Take for example fifth crusade against hussites, where crusaders ended up running moment they heard enemy singing that is before actually seeing enemy army. By that time, crusaders were convinced Hussites had satanic powers, because they'd always always be beaten by Hussites and most of time by inferior number. To proud knights, only explanation of why they're repeatedly losing to peasants despite having numerical advantage was devil.

Now imagine bringing AKs to those battles. Enemies will lose morale and run.

Comment: Heck, modern military ships don't pilot themselves alone. He's going to have to bring his own crew of minions just to avoid getting himself shipwrecked.

Answer (score 5):

TL, DR: dont bring tanks and jets, bring reliable, easy to use, easy to maintain weapons and ammunition. Revolvers, pump-action shotguns, AK-47s.

Long version:

So you want to teach medieval men and women to use tanks and jets that require years of training to master and you are only going to be there for a short while? What is the aircraft going to take off from? There's no dedicated airfields and none you can make easily. What off the tanks? With forests being much more dominant and supplies lasting maybe days if you are on the move their actions would be limited.

The best thing to bring with you is simple, rugged equipment. Crossbows were useful in the medieval times because it didnt require a lot of training to use. So you want things like AK-47's that can withstand the abuse of the little trained masses and the environments of the time. All on semi-auto ofcourse. Muskets proved that despite the downsides the psychological power of men suddenly dropping as a bullet hits is massive, so a small group of formerly crossbowmen that fire into an enemy used to swords, spears, arrows and bolts will be easily dispersed by the magic boomsticks. Besides AK-47's you want things like pump-action shotguns, revolvers, grenades. Reliable, rugged, relatively easy in operation and maintenance, capable of taking a large amount of ammunition types and thus able to be used as a type of musket with black powder for a while if you run out of standard ammunition. In fact since AK-47's are already pretty advanced for medieval people the reliance on revolver type weapons where the people can see bullets in chambers and bullets disappear from chambers could help them acclimate and learn the weapon more easily.

Just to make sure no one will screw you over you bring a few rocketlaunchers and ammunition, perhaps also a mortar. Nothing says "hello please open your doors and let me in" as an HE rocketrocket against your gate, or sudden explosives raining from the sky.